# How to get the value of the row in DataTables

Tags: ajax, grid, datatables, rows

Data tables run the following statement to see what data should fill in the ranks

```
$(document).ready( function () {
    var lastIdx = null;
    var idDoc = "<?php echo $_GET['idDoc'];?>";
    var table = $('#tformulario').DataTable( {
        "order": [[ 1, "asc" ]],
        "aProcessing": true,
        "aServerSide": true,
        "stateSave":true,
        "ajax": "{!! URL::to ('/datosFormulario?idDoc="+idDoc+"')!!}",
        "language": {
```

I like to get or save to a variable which returns the ajax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[read the docs](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax)

You can use dataSrc as a function to save the result and then return it.